# Combine knockout.js and polymer

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, polymer

is there a way to bind properties of a custom polymer-element with knockout.js?

Like this way:

```
<my-polymer-element data-bind="customproperty: vmproperty"></my-polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [attr binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html):

```
<my-polymer-element data-bind="attr: { customproperty: vmproperty }"></my-polymer-element>
```

Comment: Alright thank you, but this seems to work only one time and if the property changes, the viewmode won't notice this.

Comment: is `vmproperty` an observable? Also, if it changes `polymer` needs to be configured to use dynamic fields

Comment: There is no "of course" here on SO - if you don't show code for it, we don't know if it exists.